# How to visualize a hive data?

Tags: hive, data-visualization, flutter-hive

I am building a flutter desktop application where I have used [Hive](https://pub.dev/packages/hive) database. It creates `abc.hive` file and `abc.lock` file in my local machine. Now I want to open the `.hive` extension file and visualize the data stored in that file.

How can I visualize the hive file? I tried to load the file in [Hue](https://demo.gethue.com/hue) but couldn't do it. May be I don't know how to do it. Can anyone help me visualize the hive file?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In case you only want to display the content of the .hive file in the browser you can use hive studio:

https://studio.hivedb.dev/#/

Obviously, you're not able to edit the db but it visualizes the content of your "box".

Comment: At least this site is better than having nothing. Unfortunately it does not have horizontal scrolling bar. So not all field are visible.

Comment: Even there is no option to copy it!